# Can't find correct xpath for retweet or like button with selenium for chromedriver and python

Tags: selenium, xpath, twitter

I can't find the correct xpath to use for retweet and like on this page: https://twitter.com/snowfulls/status/1198269659465818115

Also, I need help finding the xpath for the second retweet button that comes up to confirm the retweet.

Is there a way to find xpaths automatically?

Comment: In general, it's better practice on StackOverflow to include the code or other methods which you have attempted to solve your issue. This shows a level of effort & research has been put into asking your question, and comes off less as a "write my code for me" type of question. I did not downvote your question here, but this is probably why someone else did.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question -- no, there is not a way to find XPaths automatically unless you use some kind of scanner tool. These XPaths are not always accurate though. The best approach is to use an XPath browser extension helper that will allow you to test out XPath expressions on a page in real-time. That is what I have used to help develop my solution.

To click the "Like" button on a tweet, you can use the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# ensure the above references are added to use WebDriverWait correctly

# wait for the element to exist
like_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Like']")))

# click the like button
like_button.click()
```

To click the retweet button, similarly:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# ensure the above references are added to use WebDriverWait correctly


# wait for the element to exist
retweet_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Retweet']")))

# click the retweet button
retweet_button.click()

# now, confirm the retweet:
retweet_confirm = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='retweetConfirm']")))

# click the retweet confirm button
retweet_confirm.click()
```

The above solution uses a few simple extensions of Selenium library -- mainly, `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` class. `WebDriverWait` allows us to wait up to a specified time for a condition to occur. This goes hand-in-hand with `ExpectedConditions` class, which measures the status of elements on the page to confirm whether or not a `WebElement` meets a certain condition.

So, `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located` means "Wait up to 10 seconds for the presence of a WebElement" -- this `WebElement` then gets specified in the locator strategy, `By.XPath, "...."`.

Hope this explanation helps a bit.